# Find points on the sides of an angle minimizing the perimeter of the triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The question is a slightly modified version from Kiselev's Geometry Book 1. Planimetry Exercise 95:

> Given an angle $XOY$ and an interior point $A$, find a point $B$ on
>   the side $OX$ and a point $C$ on the side $OY$ such that the perimeter
>   of the triangle $ABC$ is minimal.

The original question limits the angle to be acute, where the question is solved by introducing points symmetric to $A$ with respect to the sides of the angle. My question is whether one can find two distinct such points $B$ and $C$ if the angle is either *right* or *obtuse*. Using the same method, when the angle is right the distance is minimized if the two points coincide to the vertex of the angle, and when the angle is obtuse the points become exterior to the angle. However, I could not prove that there are no two *distinct* points *on* the sides of the angle that minimize the perimeter. 
Is there any other method to find such points or can one prove that no such points exist, i.e. the set of possible perimeters does not have the minimum?

Comment: You can use the same construction and that the hypotenuse is larger than catheti to show that the shortest polygonal loop that touches both sides is going to the vertex and back, in the case of not acute angle.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Yes, but I was wondering which points make the perimeter shortest if the points are still on the sides. I want to strictly prove that there are no distinct points on the sides with the minimum perimeter.

Comment: The minimum is when they are both at the vertex of the angle. Therefore, there is no minimum for two different points since you can make the perimeter smaller than any configuration in which the points are different by taking the points closer to the vertex

Comment: @conditionalMethod Even in the obtuse case? I'm not sure how to prove geometrically that every configuration other than the two points coinciding on the vertex is non-optimal(longer perimeter).

Comment: Draw the figure. Let $A_1, A_2$ be the reflections of $A$. Join  $A_1$ to a $B$ and $A_2$ to a $C$. Join also $B$ and $C$ and $A_1$ and $A_2$ to $O$. Assume that $AA_1$ is the one that intersects $OB$ on the other side of $O$, while $AA_2$ intersects $OC$ on the same side of $O$ as $C$. Then $A_2O$ is less than $A_2C+CO$ by triangle inequality. But $CO<BC$ because the angle is not acute. Also $A_1B<A_1O$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Thank you! You might want to make that as an answer so that I can choose your answer and close this question.